# In c# How to convert back unicoded characters to UTF-8?

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

I Have this text `Grou00dfbeerenstrau00dfe` and I need to convert it to `Großbeerenstraße`
also `Eichstu00e4tt` to `Eichstätt` 
But I don't completely understand and solve this because of these reasons:

1. ONLY some characters (special characters) are converted, not the whole text
2. Unicoded texts usually have Escape characters like `\u00df` instead of `u00df`

[image]

Could you please help me to convert correctly back to its original states?
Basically, how can I convert when there is no escape character?

NOTE: If you must know, I'm sending some special charactered strings into some system. I cannot touch this system but when I request back the same string from that system, it converts `Großbeerenstraße` to `Grou00dfbeerenstrau00dfe` and so on.

Comment: It isn't `00df`, though, it's `u00df`, so the `u` is still there, but the \ has been stripped off. This unfortunately makes the string ambiguous, but I would start with looking for every `u` and checking to see if the following 4 characters are a valid hexadecimal number.

Comment: You are correct, it is u00df but with no excape character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on David's idea of looking for `u` and checking if the following 4 characters are valid hex numbers, it would look something like this:

```
public string FixGermanUnicode(string input) {
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
        if (i < input.Length - 4 && input[i] == 'u' && input[i + 1] == '0'
                && int.TryParse(input.Substring(i + 1, 4), NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out var code)) {
            try {
                output.Append(char.ConvertFromUtf32(code));
                i += 4;
            } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
                //not a valid unicode character
                output.Append(input[i]);
            }
        } else {
            output.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return output.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(FixGermanUnicode("Grou00dfbeerenstrau00dfe"));
```

Really, it checks for `u0` to prevent cases where the next 4 characters are valid unicode, but should not have been replaced. That will work for German at least, since all the special characters in German have unicode codes starting with `0`.

This will also catch scenarios where the follow 4 digits are valid hex numbers, but the resulting hex number is not a valid unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

While I completely agree with @Gabriel Luci's answer, I would like to point out a more concise implementation of the same idea (it needs the ' System.Text.RegularExpression' namespace):

```
readonly static string unicodePattern = @"u0[0-9a-fA-F]{3}";

public static string FixGermanUnicode(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, unicodePattern, match =>
    {
        var digits = match.Value.Substring(1);
        try
        {
            return char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse(digits, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)).ToString();
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            //not a valid unicode character
            return match.Value;
        }
    });
}
```